# How to Pass Parameters from QSub to Bash Script?

Tags: parameter-passing, qsub

I'm having an issue passing variables to a Bash script using QSub.

Assume I have a Bash script named example. The format of example is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# (assume other variables have been set)

echo $1 $2 $3 $4
```

So, executing "bash example.sh this is a test" on Terminal (I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, if that helps) produces the output "this is a test".

However, when I enter "qsub -v this,is,a,test example.sh", I get no output. I checked the output file that QSub produces, but the line "this is a test" is nowhere to be found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the script you are submitting to qsub and how it calls the bash script example?

Answer (score 29):

Using PBSPro or SGE, arguments can simply be placed after the script name as may seem intuitive.

`qsub example.sh hello world`

In Torque, command line arguments can be submitted using the `-F` option. Your `example.sh` will look something like this:

`#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 $2"`

and your command like so:

`qsub -F "hello world" example.sh`

Alternatively, environment variables can be set using `-v` with a comma-separated list of variables.

`#!/bin/bash
echo "$FOO $BAR"`

and your command like so:

`qsub -v FOO="hello",BAR="world" example.sh`

(This may be better phrased as a comment on @William Hay's answer, but I don't have the reputation to do so.)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure which batch scheduler you are using but on PBSPro or SGE then submitting with `qsub example.sh this is a test` should do what you want.

The Torque batch scheduler doesn't (AFAIK) allow passing command line arguments to the script this way.  You would need to create a script looking something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $FOO
```

Then submit it with a command like:

```
qsub -v FOO="This is a test" example.sh
```