# qsub job submission with script that requires flag argument

Tags: bash, qsub

I have a script called proc.sh that has a flag option that requires an ID. To run it, I do this:

```
./proc.sh -s id
```

I am working with the TORQUE resource manager (based on OpenPBS), so I initially tried to submit this as a job with the following command, which didn't work

```
qsub -V -k o -l nodes=1:ppn=2,walltime=10:00:00 proc.sh -F id
```

I've been told that I can use the -v option, but I'm not sure how to use it properly in this case. Would this be the proper way?

```
qsub -V -k o -l nodes=1:ppn=2,walltime=10:00:00 -v "s=id" proc.sh
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925068/how-to-pass-parameters-from-qsub-to-bash-script

Comment: I got it to work by using the -v option, and within proc.sh I called the variable